# where should HADOOP_HOME variable point to on BigInsights on Cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights

I'd like to use the kite-dataset tool on BigInsights on cloud, and have installed it on the mastermanager node in my home folder as per the [installation instructions](http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.0.0/Install-Kite.html):

```
curl http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/kitesdk/kite-tools/1.0.0/kite-tools-1.0.0-binary.jar -o kite-dataset
chmod +x kite-dataset
```

However, when I try to run it, I get:

```
$ ./kite-dataset
ERROR: Cannot find Hadoop installation!
You can fix this warning by setting HADOOP_HOME
```

Where should this variable point to on BigInsights on Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is helpful, but [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCRJU_4.0.1/com.ibm.streams.toolkits.doc/doc/tk$com.ibm.streamsx.hdfs/tk$com.ibm.streamsx.hdfs$1.html) shows where HADOOP_HOME can typically be found on BigInsights 3 and 4:

> For IBM InfoSphere BigInsights 3.x:
>
> ```
> Set HADOOP_HOME to BigInsights_Install_Directory/IHC.
> For example, /opt/ibm/biginsights/IHC.
> ```
>
> For IBM InfoSphere BigInsights 4.x:
>
> ```
> Set HADOOP_HOME to BigInsights_Install_Directory/hadoop.
> For example, /usr/iop/4.0.0.0/hadoop.
> ```